# ios get text value from textfield in tableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

In my ViewController, I had created a textField with name `UITextField *txtMyName;`
After that, I was added my textField to tableViewCell `[cell addSubview:txtMyName];`

I can edit text in my textField, but when I get text from textField `_strFullName = txtMyName.text;`

But, it's get empty values.

How to I can resolve this problem!

***** Edited****

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [self setFrameTextField:cell];
        [self CustomTextField:cell :txtMyName];
        if ([[dict_infoFriend objectForKey:@"Fullname"] isEqualToString:@" "]) {
            txtMyName.placeholder = @"Name";
        }
        else{
            txtMyName.text = [dict_infoFriend objectForKey:@"Fullname"];
        }
        [cell addSubview:txtMyName];
    }
else if (indexPath.row == 1){
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            button.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - 10, 0, 130, 40);
        }
        else{
            button.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width / 2 - 65, 0, 130, 40);
        }
        [self CustomBTN:button];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickDone) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:button];
    }
```

Comment: _strFullName = cell.txtMyName.text; do it

Comment: How many cells in your table view ??

Comment: No! I cannot call cell.txtMyName.text. Because, I'm not created in TableViewCell.

Comment: I had created in myViewController, after that, I added to cell to show in tableView

Comment: Do you have any button to get the text after edited? Or you have to get it without interaction?

Comment: So, I cannot call cell.txtMyName.text

Comment: hi Please put some code here for batter understanding ..

Comment: In my tableView, I added textField for row == 0.
and added 1 button for row == 1.
I want to click this button, I will get value of textField

Comment: I had edited my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have added the textfield into table cell, you've to get the cell first then using tag of textfield you can get the text.

Try like this,

Assume that you have tag for textfield like `txtMyName.tag = 100`

```
-(void) ClickDone {
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath];
     UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
     _strFullName = txtField.text;
  }
```

Comment: It's worked. thanks. But, when click done, it wil create UITextField, So it's take memory

Comment: If so you can straight away get the text like this, `_strFullName = ((UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:100]).text`

Comment: @IOSDeveloper Since we haven't created any `alloc` for `cell` or `txtField`, it doesn't hold memory for it. Just we are taking the already allocated objects using indexpath and tag. So, It won't take any memory.

Comment: I understand! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't assign memory to your textfield yet thats why you are able to edit but not able to retrive it. just write `txtMyName = [[UITextfield alloc]init];`  you can assign frame to textfield like `txtMyName = [[UITextfield alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];` once you assign memory to your textfield then you will be retrive the text from textfield

Comment: I have assign memory and setframe to my textfield.

Comment: txtMyName  = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - 100, 0, 300, 40)];

Comment: This is methods I had called to assign memory and frame for textField.
[self setFrameTextField:cell];
you can see in my code.